how to record websocket calls for doing performance/loadtesting?
I am trying to perform a load testing on a website which uses blazor/SignalR framework. so till the login it is sending https calls directly but after the login is completed, wss protocol is established and the communication happens only through messages. The messages are binary coded.
Thanks
I went through other tutorials and blogs but couldn't get a practical solution. Can anyone help me with this? and what should be the approach?
So how can I record these calls and create dynamics scripts on Jmeter, Load runner etc. tools?

If you want to record WebSocket traffic using JMeter you can do this using your browser developer tools and har-convertor-jmeter-plugin
The plugin can be installed using JMeter Plugins Manager
For running several requests in parallel using 1 thread (virtual user) you can use Parallel Controller
